# Blank rep in Reputation tab and no upvote count

Tags: support, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Why is this happening?

https://stackoverflow.com/users/379550/tomislav-markovski?tab=reputation

It says there's an upvote, but there's no count. Reputation stays the same.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum daily reputation from **upvotes** is capped at 200. Any additional upvotes will not give you reputation, although it does count for vote-related badges.